# How to train GitHub's "explore repositories" recommendations?

Tags: github

I find the the "explore repositories" feature in GitHub useful to discover new tools and libraries - or at least I *used* to find it useful. As of mid-summer 2019 it seems GitHub changed its algorithm on what to show to me in the "explore repositories" view, and it seems to now think that I am interested in things that I am not actually interested in, but was 7 years ago.

Is there a way to train GitHub's recommendation engine to show me content that I want to see and am interested in?